# Azure pipelines connect to private docker registry

Tags: azure, docker, azure-pipelines

I have a dedicated server with a private docker registry setup so I can push and pull images. I can connect to this server via `docker login <my_domain>`. I need to build an image using Azure Pipelines and push it to my registry, but when I try to make a docker connection, there is no way to access the private registry. Only docker hub, azure registry and "other" which still require docker id and password. Is there a way to connect Azure to my registry?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i figured out myself. It's not possible in this task, but u can change task from "Docker build" to "Bash script" and do `docker login <your_domain>:<port> -u <your_username> -p <your_password>` and then run anything you want, here specifically docker build.

Comment: What's the name of the task template you were trying to run it with before?